# Is there an md5mesh/md5anim importer/exporter for blender 2.8x?

Tags: md5, blender, blender-2.76

I've been looking for an importer / exporter of md5mesh and md5anim formats for blender for a couple of hours, with no result. I tried a few of github but they didn't work for version 2.80. I used an earlier version and although if I loaded the add-on, the md5mesh files did not load correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like KozGit done pretty good job:

[MD5 Importer/Exporter for Blender 2.80+ by KozGit](https://github.com/KozGit/Blender-2.8-MD5-import-export-addon)